# How to configure Currency field?

Tags: column, list-definition

How to set currency symbol for a field (in list definition)?

```
<Field ID="{1706A5C3-AC44-4685-A075-6019FAF9D940}" Name="Budget" DisplayName="Volumen (in €)" Type="Currency"  />
```

SharePoint is in English, but I want value to be displayed in €, instead of default $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the `LCID` attribute? I think that is the one you should try!

```
<Field ID="{1706A5C3-AC44-4685-A075-6019FAF9D940}" Name="Budget" 
DisplayName="Volumen (in €)" Type="Currency" LCID="1033"  />
```

ofcourse replacing "1033" with the wanted local (like 1045 for Polish)

**Edit**

Per MSDN:

> Optional Integer. The LCID attribute can be used to specify the
>   country/region whose currency format is being used, for example, 1033
>   for the United States.
>
> Two special cases involve the euro symbol format. If LCID=-1
>   (0xFFFFFFF), the euro symbol is added as a prefix to the number. If
>   LCID=-2 (0xFFFFFFE), the euro symbol is added as a suffix to the
>   number. The number of decimal digits is 2, although this can be
>   overridden by the Decimals attribute of the field. The euro currency
>   symbol is equal to 0x20AC in UCS-2.