# How to handle FieldCurrency in CSOM to Set Currency format using Enum

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How to set Currency Format like ₹ 123,456.00(India). We can set it by using the Sharepoint Online. I want to know how to set it by using CSOM. Is there any `enum` Type to set `CurrencyLocaleId`. Thank You.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://rohith.sharepoint.com/sites/site"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
            ListCreationInformation listinfo = new ListCreationInformation();
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom List");
            context.Load(list);

            FieldCurrency fieldCurrency = context.CastTo<FieldCurrency>(list.AddField("Price", "Currency"));
            //Here how to set Currency Format
            fieldCurrency.CurrencyLocaleId = 1081;

            fieldCurrency.Update();
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

            ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            listItem["Title"] = "Books";
            listItem["Quentity"] = 12;
            listItem["Price"] = 100;

            listItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Please, don't ask the same question again, you can edit your original post instead of deleting it!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet instead of the `FieldCurrency` approach that you are taking right now. Please modify the `xmlField` as per your requirement. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
string xmlField = "<Field ID=\"{ 1706A5C3 - AC44 - 4685 - A075 - 6019FAF9D940}\" Name=\"Budget\" DisplayName = \"Volumen (in €)\" Type = \"Currency\" LCID = \"1033\" />";

list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(xmlField, true, ddFieldOptions.AddFieldToDefaultView);
```

Source - [How to configure Currency Field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98959/how-to-configure-currency-field)